# Why does my calculator show undefined when I press any button?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Why does the calculator I coded with JavaScript, HTML and CSS show undefined when I press any/every button on the calculator? I searched for some solutions but the only one I found was that using == was incorrect and would create this problem but I did not use == in any of my code. I'm pretty new to JavaScript so I'm pretty lost.

I added my HTML, JavaScript and CSS below. I do notice though with my Javascript when I change around = .value+val; (Undefined then goes away but then it just stays blank)

```js
function clk(val){

    document.getElementById("screen").value=document.getElementById("screen").value+val;
}

function clrdisp(){
    document.getElementById("screen").value=""
}

function eql(){
    var text=document.getElementById("screen").value;
    var result=eval(text);
    document.getElementById("screen").value=result
}
```

```css
body{
    background: whitesmoke;
}


#mainbody{
    margin-left: 40%;
    margin-top: 2px;
    background: linear-gradient(#eeaeca, #94bbe9);
    width: 350px;
    height: 450px;
    border: solid 6px;
    border-color: #708193;
    border-radius: 12px;
}
#screen{
    border-width: 5px;
    margin-left: 18px;
    width: 85%;
    height: 4ipx;
    margin-top: 13px;
    border-color: #708193;
    border-radius: 8px;
    font-size: xx-large;
    font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.but{
    width: 248px;
    height: 334px;
    margin-left: 1px;
}
button{
    width: 37px;
    height: 45px;
    margin-top: 16px;
    background: linear-gradient(#22c1c3, #708193);
    margin-left: 16px;
    border: solid pink;
    border-radius: 34px;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
button:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    background: linear-gradient(#eeaeca, #708193);
    
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Calculator</title>
        <link type="text/css" href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="javascript.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="mainbody">   
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="screen">
    </div> 
    <div class="but">
        <div class="row">
            <button onclick="clk()">C</button>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <button onclick="clk()">9</button>
            <button onclick="clk()">8</button>
            <button onclick="clk()">7</button>
            <button onclick="clk()">/</button>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <button onclick="clk()">4</button>
            <button onclick="clk()">5</button>
            <button onclick="clk()">6</button>
            <button onclick="clk()">X</button>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <button onclick="clk()">1</button>
            <button onclick="clk()">2</button>
            <button onclick="clk()">3</button>
            <button onclick="clk()">-</button>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <button onclick="clk()">0</button>
            <button onclick="clk()">.</button>
            <button onclick="clk()">=</button>
            <button onclick="clk()">+</button>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because the initial value is an empty string, and `val` in your function is undefined because you aren't passing the number into the function when you call it. You just have `clk()`

Comment: Also note that it just says `clk()` for every button, you aren't even calling the other two functions in your `C` and `=` buttons.

Comment: Well, first your `clk` function is expecting a `val` argument, and you're not passing it one in any of the listeners. You may also want to think about using [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) to hold the button id, and [event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/) so you only have one listener attached to a parent that deals with the events from the buttons.

Comment: Just a side warning: The use of `eval()` can go into heavy security issue. Have an eye on it.

Comment: `function clk(val){` and `clk()` So why would it not be undefined when you pass nothing to it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thats because you don't pass `val` variable when executing `clk()` function from button.

You need to either execute the function like this: `clk([number])` or make a function with sender argument.

Comment: Thank you so much for your feedback as I noticed my stupid mistake in leaving the brackets empty with clk()

Answer (score 0):

You have to add value attribute to your buttons and pass that value to clk(this.value) function onclick, and then write your own logic whatever you want to do

Please check below code snippet

```js
function clk(val) {
  document.getElementById('screen').value =
    document.getElementById('screen').value + val;
}

function clrdisp(val) {
  document.getElementById('screen').value = '';
}

function eql(val) {
  var text = document.getElementById('screen').value;
  var result = eval(text);
  document.getElementById('screen').value = result;
}
```

```css
body{
  background: whitesmoke;
}


#mainbody{
  margin-left: 40%;
  margin-top: 2px;
  background: linear-gradient(#eeaeca, #94bbe9);
  width: 350px;
  height: 450px;
  border: solid 6px;
  border-color: #708193;
  border-radius: 12px;
}
#screen{
  border-width: 5px;
  margin-left: 18px;
  width: 85%;
  height: 4ipx;
  margin-top: 13px;
  border-color: #708193;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-size: xx-large;
  font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.but{
  width: 248px;
  height: 334px;
  margin-left: 1px;
}
button{
  width: 37px;
  height: 45px;
  margin-top: 16px;
  background: linear-gradient(#22c1c3, #708193);
  margin-left: 16px;
  border: solid pink;
  border-radius: 34px;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
button:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
  background: linear-gradient(#eeaeca, #708193);
  
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Calculator</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="mainbody">   
      <div>
          <input type="text" id="screen">
      </div> 
      <div class="but">
          <div class="row">
              <button value="C" onclick="clrdisp(this.value)">C</button>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
              <button value="9" onclick="clk(this.value)">9</button>
              <button value="8" onclick="clk(this.value)">8</button>
              <button value="7" onclick="clk(this.value)">7</button>
              <button value="/" onclick="clk(this.value)">/</button>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
              <button value="4" onclick="clk(this.value)">4</button>
              <button value="5" onclick="clk(this.value)">5</button>
              <button value="6" onclick="clk(this.value)">6</button>
              <button value="*" onclick="clk(this.value)">*</button>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
              <button value="1" onclick="clk(this.value)">1</button>
              <button value="2" onclick="clk(this.value)">2</button>
              <button value="3" onclick="clk(this.value)">3</button>
              <button value="-" onclick="clk(this.value)">-</button>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
              <button value="0" onclick="clk(this.value)">0</button>
              <button value="." onclick="clk(this.value)">.</button>
              <button value="=" onclick="eql(this.value)">=</button>
              <button value="+" onclick="clk(this.value)">+</button>
      </div>
  </div>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your feedback on this one, I see how I totally messed up with the clk and not adding value attributes, I was also struggling on how to actually add those value attributes but you really helped with that. I see now actually how dumb of me it was to leave the clk() brackets empty

Comment: I am however struggling to get the calculator to produce the result of the sum/answer, it just shows those numbers on the calculator screen but when I select = there is no answer result, do you perhaps have any advice on what I'm doing wrong in my javascript.js code. I though this would work:                                                          function eql() {
    var text = document.getElementById('screen').value;
    var result = eval(text);
    document.getElementById('screen').value = result;
  }

Comment: Edited the code run and check. Added the eql() function onclick of = button and clrdisp() method onclick of C button, please do check and let me know if you face any issues.

Comment: For multiplication changed X to *

Comment: Thank you so much I added eql() and clrdisp() on the = and the C button and the calculator is working perfectly thank you.

Comment: Glad that helped you can you please mark the answer as accepted which will help others.

Comment: Thank you @Anna for letting me know about the accepting correct answering.